# Is Parse service down right now?

Tags: parse-platform

I can't access Parse.com dashboard for at least a few minutes now.
I try refreshing and from different browsers and keep getting the same errors - 500 There’s been an error, but it’s not your fault.
If you keep seeing this, check the help page for more info. 
I also tried going for the help page but it is written that Parse is healthy.

Comment: Yes, service is down at the moment, although they said the issue was resolved: https://status.parse.com/

Comment: can't reach anything parse-related too